# inoremap <Tab> <Esc> and <C-I> <Tab>

Tags: vim

How it's use together?

```
inoremap <Tab> <Esc> 

inoremap <C-I> <Tab>
```

Comment: do you know why you have the two lines?

Comment: hi, @Kent. I dont understand u

Comment: ok, explain what did you mean "how (to) use this and that". are you asking how to execute the two lines? or what will the two lines do? or what

Comment: This should never work since `<C-I>` and `<Tab>` are the same in vim

Comment: @Kent two lines together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you intend to do (your question is too terse), due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.